# Schedules Folder Backup

Tags: windows, backup

i have some folders in C drive on which i work on daily basis and the data in them is very critical.. so every night when i shutdown my PC i `copy` -> `paste` -> `overwrite existing files`  these folders to a separate location...  so that of the system crashed or something bad happens.. i will be able to easily format C and all

i cannot move these folders from C drive because these folders include `C:\wamp\www\` of WAMP server and such folders...

is there a tool on which i can schedule that everyday at X time these folders will be backuped to 'Y' path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose [Cobian Backup](http://www.educ.umu.se/~cobian/cobianbackup.htm) can do this. It has the ability to backup locked files.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and install skydrive or dropbox.
2. Type in a command window with administrative rights:
   `mklink /d "C:\Users\(Username)\SkyDrive\<name of folder to create>"

   "<exact path to folder you want backed up>"`

Example for a network or mapped drive
`mklink /d "C:\Users\Michael\SkyDrive\Documents\Office"
"\\PC-2\My Documents\My Pictures"`

Example for a local folder
`mklink /d "C:\Users\Michael\SkyDrive\Documents\Office"
"C:\Users\Michael\Pictures"`